# JS assignment order of properties in objects

Tags: javascript, properties, javascript-objects

Just had a quick question about why a certain order of assignment works and another doesn't.

I wanted to create a simple "inherit" / "copy" function (just for testing it) that copies properties from one object to another:

```
var cat = { tail:"yes", hairy:"yes, hairy" };
var dog = { sick:"extremely ill"};

function inherit(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var p in obj1) 
    {
    obj2[p] = obj1[p]; // this works, but "obj1[p] = obj2[p];" doesn't. Why??
    }
}

inherit(cat, dog);

console.log(dog.tail);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over all the properties of `obj1`, so all those properties exist on `obj1`.

If you try to copy from `obj2` then you are trying to copy properties that don't exist (on that object), so you cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the properties `var p in obj1`, so those indexes only necessarily exist in `obj1`. As such, trying to assign `obj1[p] = obj2[p];` won't work as expected, since there is no guarantee (and in your particular example this is certainly the case) that `obj[p]` is defined. This assignment will simply assign `undefined` to indexes in `obj1` that don't exist in `obj2` and copy the values whose indexes do exist in `obj2`.

You need to loop over each object's properties separately (i.e. two loops), although this also isn't a good idea, since any values with the same index on both object will result in one being wiped out. What are you actually trying to achieve by this? It seems a very dangerous/volatile thing to do.

Comment: +1 Of course, OP could control for where both objects have a particular key with at least `obj2[p] = obj2[p] || obj1[p];` (or some variant if you might be assigning falsy values). If it's just a programming exercise to learn about loops and assignment, it's a fair question, IMO.

Comment: @Bryan, I didn't mean the question isn't a valid one, just that the intention/purpose of the code is unclear and not well defined. You could do many things with clashing keys, my problem was that the OP's intention in such a case was unclear.